# Is there a way to prevent macOS's archive utility from unarchiving inner zip files?

Tags: macos, zip, archive-utility

I have a zip file, within it I have another zip file, and within that file I have a txt file. When I unzip the outermost file with Apple's archive utility, it unarchives the inner files automatically. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Archive Utility has a Prefs panel - though it's not obvious how to get there.
The app itself is in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications`. Go to that folder, launch the Utility by double-clicking, then under the app name in the menu bar, choose Preferences.

[image]

Uncheck 'Keep expanding if possible'.

There is a way to expose this pref panel in the regular System Preferences Panel, which needs something like [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) to activate.

Comment: It wan't run on my macOS Monterey (

Comment: It's still there in Ventura. Use Spotlight to find it if you struggle.